# Can't find full text search in SQL Server 2019 Setup

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried to import a database into SSMS and because there were queries with full text search that failed. So i tried to install full text search on the SQL server 2019 but i just can't find the checkbox in the setup.

[image]

I searched all over the web but only found tutorials on how to install full text search and nobody seemed to have the same problem as me.

I selected this path for the SQL server and installed the "basic" version.

[image]

Comment: "Select the Express features to install". Full-text search is [explicitly documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-version-15#Programmability) to be unavailable for Express. This restriction is not new to 2019, by the way. Use a supported edition (like Developer, which is functionally Enterprise with the restriction that you can't use it for production work).

Comment: Alright thank you very much. Can you post your comment as an aswer so i can check it as correct? :)

Comment: @JeroenMostert If you look closer at the feature chart, it is supported for `Express with Advanced Services` - while I agree Developer is a better way to go (if it's not for production), technically, the OP needs the other installer, not a different edition.

Comment: @AaronBertrand do i have to reinstall the whole server if i want to change the installer? Cause that would be a bit bad since i'm already working with the basic since 4 months.

Comment: I don't think so but to be honest I haven't tried it with modern versions. My primary computer is not a Windows PC or I'd try right now. If you moved to Developer you'd have to do that too though... I don't believe there's an upgrade path from Express to Developer. So, give it a try, and if [the full installer (either of the right two)](https://www.solvps.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Screen-Shot-2017-08-08-at-2.49.04-PM.png) won't let you add the feature, back up your databases (which you should be doing anyway), install the right instance that you need, then restore your databases.

Comment: Alright thank @AaronBertrand i think i'll give it a try like you said.

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand it worked perfect and i didn't even need to reinstall the server :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the installer to "custom" like @AaronBertrand said and it worked perfect.

[image]

I didn't even need to reinstall the whole server and all databases were still there.
If you have the same problem still make a backup of all your database just in case.